# passing parameter from middleware nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, middleware

```
if (token_count == 1) {
    var user_name = rows[0].user_name;
    next();
} else {
    data = {
        message :"Invalid Token"
    }
    res.send(data);
}
```

I need to pass user_name as a parameter from next(), the function which it gets called is as bellow,

```
router.post('/dashboard', function (req, res) {
    // user_name must be fetched here
    console.log("middleware next")
});
```

Comment: i have solved it by  using res.locals 
res.locals.user_name = user_name;

Answer (score 0):

You can add data to the req object

```
if (token_count == 1) {
          var user_name = rows[0].user_name;
          req.user_name = user_name; 
            next();
        }else{
          data = {
            message :"Invalid Token"
          }
          res.send(data);
        }


    router.post('/dashboard', function (req, res) {
    // user_name must be fetched here
    console.log(req.user_name)
    });
```